# Comparing clock times in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time

I'm currently working on a table in Oracle database where there are time values stored in AM/PM format. By default, the times are a VARCHAR2 datatype so I have been converting them using the to_date function.

What I'm doing is comparing two different times within the table and running a query which should return the results for all times contained within that interval. The interval is acquired by using the between condition. Here is an example:

```
SELECT TIME
FROM   TIME_TABLE
WHERE  to_date(TIME,'HH:MI:SS PM') between 
       to_date('04:00:00 PM', 'HH:MI:SS PM') and 
       to_date('08:00:00 PM', 'HH:MI:SS PM');
```

The problem is that when you do not declare the date using the to_date function, it will automatically default to the 1st of the current month. Thus, if I wanted to get all the results from 11:59 PM to 12:00 AM I will get incorrect results.

Basically, I want to calculate the time interval in a manner where it loops instead of going only in one direction as it does naturally. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Obviously you should never store dates as varchar in your database. Is there any reason why you don't use timestamp?

Comment: @popovitsj unfortunately it is not a database I created. It's one that I'm currently working on that has already been established. Would using timestamp fix this problem?

Comment: why not just convert it before comparing??

Comment: @JohnRuddell I don't believe it actually will make a difference in this case. Even if I convert it before, since there is no day/month/year portion, I'm still going to run into the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest problem here is that as you add more data things will get slower and slower.  It's difficult for an index to be efficiently used when you are calling a function on the field itself.  It will have to scan the entire table to satisfy the query.  There are three ways to avoid this:

- Don't store dates or times as strings.  Use the correct field type.  This is the best approach.
- Compare using strings instead of converting first.  This will only work if you have guaranteed lexicographic ordering.  You can do this with 24-hour times, but not with 12-hour times, because AM/PM gets in the way.
- As Barett enlightened me in comments, Oracle has the concept of [Function-Based Indexes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10471/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS00505).  You could create one that pre-computes the results of `to_date`, such that when you use it in the query that it has an index to work against.  There are several [disadvantages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10471/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS257) though, so if you take this approach, I suggest you consider the consequences carefully.

With regard to the question about looping over midnight on a time-only value, the general algorithm is as follows:

- Is the start-of-range value <= the end-of-range value?

  - If yes, then the return true if the test value is >= the start-of-range **and** < the end-of-range.  Else return false.
  - If no, then return true if the test value is >= the start-of-range **or** < the end-of-range.  Else return false.

There's no need to use :59, or any other value of the sort.  Doing so can get in the way of other things, such as taking the duration of the range or testing a value like :59.5.

Comment: "There's no way that an index can be efficiently used when you are calling a function on the field itself." Not true; Oracle has function-based indexes. Fola would just need to add one. Granted this still has "code smell".

Comment: @Barett - Very interesting.  I did not know about those!  Reading [these docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10471/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS00505), it still seems like there a lot of disadvantages though.  But thanks for the info!

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Unbelievable...I don't know why I did not think of having two separate cases depending on the ranges. For some reason I was mentally stuck on doing it using only AND or OR. Thanks for the informative post.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You'll need to add some logic for detecting a "loop" in your between criteria. If there is a loop (endRange < startRange), then the criteria should be:

```
    to_char(to_date(TIME,'HH:MI:SS PM'),'HH24:MI:SS') >= '08:00:00' // endRange
 OR to_char(to_date(TIME,'HH:MI:SS PM'),'HH24:MI:SS') <= '04:00:00' // startRange
```

On a side note, I reiterate wolφi's suggestion to use 24 hour time. Otherwise you'll have AM/PM problems too.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you convert from an am/pm varchar to a 24h varchar and compare that one with `BETWEEN`?

```
SELECT TIME 
  FROM TIME_TABLE
 WHERE to_char(to_date(TIME,'HH:MI:SS PM'),'HH24:MI:SS') 
         BETWEEN '04:00:00' AND '05:00:00';
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't change anything. If you are comparing 23:59(11:59PM) to 00:30:00 (12:30AM) for instance, you won't actually be able to the the times between those since the char type can only check between two values if the first value is higher than the other. Since 23 is lower than 00, you will never get anything for a result.

Comment: Now I got what you meant with "loops". BETWEEN '23:10' AND '00:30' should be a valid clause and return all times between 23:10 and 23:59, and between 00:00 and 00:30, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the second time is 'earlier' than the first one, and adjust it to the following day if it is. you need to adjust the table time in the same way. Using CTEs just so you don't have to repeat the string values and conversions:

```
WITH R AS (
  SELECT to_date('11:59:00 PM', 'HH:MI:SS PM') start_t,
         to_date('12:00:00 AM', 'HH:MI:SS PM') end_t
  FROM   DUAL
),
T AS (
  SELECT to_date(TIME,'HH:MI:SS PM') AS TIME
  FROM TIME_TABLE
)
SELECT to_char(TIME, 'HH:MI:SS PM')
FROM   R
JOIN   T
ON     T.time + case when T.time < R.start_t then 1 else 0 end
       between R.start_t and 
         R.end_t + case when R.end_t < R.start_t then 1 else 0 end
ORDER BY T.time + case when T.time < R.start_t then 1 else 0 end;
```

Which isn't very pleasant.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9bf26/2).

Hopefully this is a small table and you won't see the performance issues Matt Johnson referred to...

You could avoid that by generating all possible times in your range and comparing those with the real table as strings:

```
WITH R AS (
  SELECT to_date('11:10:00 PM', 'HH:MI:SS PM') start_t,
         to_date('12:30:00 AM', 'HH:MI:SS PM') end_t
  FROM   DUAL
),
T AS (
  SELECT level AS rn,
         to_char(start_t
             + numtodsinterval(level - 1, 'SECOND'),
           'HH:MI:SS PM') AS time
  FROM R
  CONNECT BY level <= 86400 *
    (end_t + case when end_t < start_t then 1 else 0 end - start_t)
)
SELECT TT.time
FROM   T
JOIN   TIME_TABLE TT
ON     TT.time = T.time
ORDER BY T.rn;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9bf26/4).

The first CTE just stops you repeating the string again. The second uses the first as a base and uses a `CONNECT BY` to find all the times in between, adding the number of seconds between the start and (adjusted) second string times. That wraps to the next day, but it doesn't matter as it's converted back to a string and loses the date part; and *that* string is then used as the filter for your real table.

You'd have the same issues with 24-hour time, since there is still no date portion, but it might make the logic a bit easier to follow. It's so long since I've done anything with 12-hour times that it's very hard to type '12' for midnight...